# Excel Group Data, Get Mode and Total

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have the following Dataset in excel. After each product ends, the total is given in the next row and a '*" sign will be present before the 'total' row.

```
        Product Type    Cost
        A   1   10
        A   1   20
        A   2   10
        A   1   20
    *   A       60
        B   1   30
        B   7   10
        B   7   30
        B   4   50
   *    B       120
        C   3   10
        C   4   50
        C   4   30
        C   4   25
        C   4   20
        C   4   15
        C   3   10
        C   4   5
     *  C       165
```

I want to get the MODE of each TYPE for Each product. and the total of the Costs for EACH product. Its best if they can be listed by product name.

For example, the output should be,

```
A 1 60
B 7 120
C 4 165
```

How can I achieve this? Either using excel formulas or VBA is fine.
Please help.
Thank you...

Comment: Have you manually inserted those subtotals or are they the result of applying the in-built Subtotal feature (Data tab)?

Comment: No. They're also coming with the data set. This is just the way the dataset comes.

Comment: But if you want  only the rows with totals, you can filter your rows using filter on column("Type") only empty cells. 
that will show is exactly  that you want. Otherwise post your ask with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the source table as you give it is in `A1:D20` (with headers in row 1 and such that column A contains asterisks (*) only) and that the results table as you give it is in `F2:H4`, then:

In `G2`, **array formula****:

`=MODE(IF(B$2:B$20=F2,{1,1}*C$2:C$20))`

*Edit*: As per your comment, if the *Type* column may contain non-numerics:

`=INDEX(C$2:C$20,MODE(IF(B$2:B$20=F2,IF(C$2:C$20<>"",MATCH(C$2:C$20,C$2:C$20,{0,0})))))`

In `H2`:

`=SUMIF(B$2:B$20,F2,D$2:D$20)/2`

Copy both down as required.

Note that, if more than one value shares the highest frequency (i.e. there is technically no single modal value), then, of those values, the first found will be returned.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Wow this works greeeaaat. Thanx alooooooooooot! 
 :) Regards!

Comment: Hello.. This works great untill there are non numeric values in the TYPE column.. what happens if a type like 1A 2A 1X come? How do i get the MODE then? Thank you

Comment: Added to the post.

Comment: Hello... Sorry to bother you again... I have another small question....

Comment: Hello... Sorry to bother you again... I have another small question.... in the above dataset,  How can I return the Type of the Highest total cost of each product? for example,  Product "A", the highest cost is from Type 1 with a total cost of 50. so it should return 1. But in product "B", although the MODE is 7, the highest cost is from Type 4 with a cost of 50. so it should return 4. and product "C" highest cost is 145 in type 4.  How can I achieve this? Thank you soo much for your time

Comment: Using the same tables as indicated, in I2: =LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+SUMIFS(D$2:D$20,B$2:B$20,F2,C$2:C$20,C$2:C$20))),C$2:C$20) and copy down.

Answer (score 0):

given your data "structure" a possible VBA approach could be the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, firstCell As Range
    Dim iProduct As Long

    With Worksheets("Dataset") '<--| change "Dataset" with your actual worksheet name
        Set firstCell = .Range("A2") '<--| set first cell for the current "Product" range
        For Each cell In .Columns(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(, 2) '<--| loop through "asterisks" in column "A"
            iProduct = iProduct + 1 '<--| update "Product" counter
            .Range("F1:H1").Offset(iProduct) = Array(cell.Offset(, -1).Value, _
                                                     Application.WorksheetFunction.Mode(Range(firstCell, cell).Value), _
                                                     cell.Offset(, 1).Value)
            Set firstCell = cell.Offset(1) '<--| set first cell for the next "Product" range
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

where I assumed:
- data are in columns "A:D", with "asterisks" in column "A" 
- output in column "F:H" from row 1 downwards